"Resolving Bluetooth Connectivity Issue with Flutter Blue Plus Library"
I copied code from one of the projects, but the code was working with an old version of the Flutter Blue Plus library, so I am getting several errors. I want to know the solution.
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '/control_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter BLE Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final FlutterBluePlus flutterBlue = FlutterBluePlus.instance;
  final List<BluetoothDevice> _devicesList = [];
  List<BluetoothService>? bluetoothServices;
  List<ControlButton> controlButtons = [];
  String? readableValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initBleList();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future initBleList() async {
    await Permission.bluetooth.request();
    await Permission.bluetoothConnect.request();
    await Permission.bluetoothScan.request();
    await Permission.bluetoothAdvertise.request();
    flutterBlue.connectedDevices.asStream().listen((devices) {
      for (var device in devices) {
        _addDeviceTolist(device);
      }
    });
    flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((scanResults) {
      for (var result in scanResults) {
        _addDeviceTolist(result.device);
      }
    });
    flutterBlue.startScan();
  }

  void _addDeviceTolist(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (!_devicesList.contains(device)) {
      setState(() {
        _devicesList.add(device);
      });
    }
  }

I am trying to configure functions and methods to call them later in the widget, but the following errors appear:
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "use_of_void_result",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/use_of_void_result",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.\nTry checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 33,
    "startColumn": 39,
    "endLineNumber": 33,
    "endColumn": 63
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "instance_access_to_static_member",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/instance_access_to_static_member",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The static getter 'connectedDevices' can't be accessed through an instance.\nTry using the class 'FlutterBluePlus' to access the getter.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 50,
    "startColumn": 17,
    "endLineNumber": 50,
    "endColumn": 33
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "undefined_method",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/undefined_method",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The method 'asStream' isn't defined for the type 'List'.\nTry correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'asStream'.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 50,
    "startColumn": 34,
    "endLineNumber": 50,
    "endColumn": 42
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "instance_access_to_static_member",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/instance_access_to_static_member",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The static getter 'scanResults' can't be accessed through an instance.\nTry using the class 'FlutterBluePlus' to access the getter.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 55,
    "startColumn": 17,
    "endLineNumber": 55,
    "endColumn": 28
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "instance_access_to_static_member",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/instance_access_to_static_member",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The static method 'startScan' can't be accessed through an instance.\nTry using the class 'FlutterBluePlus' to access the method.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 60,
    "startColumn": 17,
    "endLineNumber": 60,
    "endColumn": 26
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "deprecated_member_use",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/deprecated_member_use",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "'instance' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. No longer needed, remove this from your code.\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 33,
    "startColumn": 55,
    "endLineNumber": 33,
    "endColumn": 63,
    "tags": [
        2
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "deprecated_member_use",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/deprecated_member_use",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "'name' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use platformName instead.\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 78,
    "startColumn": 76,
    "endLineNumber": 78,
    "endColumn": 80,
    "tags": [
        2
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "deprecated_member_use",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/deprecated_member_use",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "'name' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use platformName instead.\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 84,
    "startColumn": 69,
    "endLineNumber": 84,
    "endColumn": 73,
    "tags": [
        2
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "deprecated_member_use",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/deprecated_member_use",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "'id' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use remoteId instead.\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 84,
    "startColumn": 88,
    "endLineNumber": 84,
    "endColumn": 90,
    "tags": [
        2
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "deprecated_member_use",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/deprecated_member_use",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 2,
    "message": "'name' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use platformName instead.\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 88,
    "startColumn": 30,
    "endLineNumber": 88,
    "endColumn": 34,
    "tags": [
        2
    ]
}]

The errors are as follows:[{
"resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#0",
"code": {
"value": "use_of_void_result",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"path": "/diagnostics/use_of_void_result",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 8,
"message": "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.\nTry checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 33,
"startColumn": 39,
"endLineNumber": 33,
"endColumn": 63
},{
"resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#0",
"code": {
"value": "instance_access_to_static_member",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"path": "/diagnostics/instance_access_to_static_member",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 8,
"message": "The static getter 'connectedDevices' can't be accessed through an instance.\nTry using the class 'FlutterBluePlus' to access the getter.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 50,
"startColumn": 17,
"endLineNumber": 50,
"endColumn": 33
},{
"resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#0",
"code": {
"value": "undefined_method",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"path": "/diagnostics/undefined_method",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 8,
"message": "The method 'asStream' isn't defined for the type 'List'.\nTry correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'asStream'.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 50,
"startColumn": 34,
"endLineNumber": 50,
"endColumn": 42
},{
"resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#0",
"code": {
"value": "instance_access_to_static_member",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"path": "/diagnostics/instance_access_to_static_member",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 8,
"message": "The static getter 'scanResults' can't be accessed through an instance.\nTry using the class 'FlutterBluePlus' to access the getter.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 55,
"startColumn": 17,
"endLineNumber": 55,
"endColumn": 28
},{
"resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#0",
"code": {
"value": "instance_access_to_static_member",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"path": "/diagnostics/instance_access_to_static_member",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 8,
"message": "The static method 'startScan' can't be accessed through an instance.\nTry using the class 'FlutterBluePlus' to access the method.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 60,
"startColumn": 17,
"endLineNumber": 60,
"endColumn": 26
},{
"resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#0",
"code": {
"value": "deprecated_member_use",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"path": "/diagnostics/deprecated_member_use",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 2,
"message": "'instance' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. No longer needed, remove this from your code.\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 33,
"startColumn": 55,
"endLineNumber": 33,
"endColumn": 63,
"tags": [
2
]
},{
"resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#0",
"code": {
"value": "deprecated_member_use",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"path": "/diagnostics/deprecated_member_use",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 2,
"message": "'name' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use platformName instead.\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 78,
"startColumn": 76,
"endLineNumber": 78,
"endColumn": 80,
"tags": [
2
]
},{
"resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#0",
"code": {
"value": "deprecated_member_use",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"path": "/diagnostics/deprecated_member_use",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 2,
"message": "'name' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use platformName instead.\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 84,
"startColumn": 69,
"endLineNumber": 84,
"endColumn": 73,
"tags": [
2
]
},{
"resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#0",
"code": {
"value": "deprecated_member_use",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"path": "/diagnostics/deprecated_member_use",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 2,
"message": "'id' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use remoteId instead.\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 84,
"startColumn": 88,
"endLineNumber": 84,
"endColumn": 90,
"tags": [
2
]
},{
"resource": "/c:/Users/lomaux/Desktop/flutter_ble-main/lib/main.dart",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#0",
"code": {
"value": "deprecated_member_use",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"path": "/diagnostics/deprecated_member_use",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 2,
"message": "'name' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use platformName instead.\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 88,
"startColumn": 30,
"endLineNumber": 88,
"endColumn": 34,
"tags": [
2
]
}]

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
